# C++ - What type of parameters should I accept? (When should we cast?)

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm using mysql++, where we need to form queries and thus there's necessity to do a type check before we send it to mysql++ wrapper and the database. In some cases, we need something like `uid` which is basically an `int` type. However, I can also accept a `std::string` and check if I can turn it into an integer number. In some interpret languages, there is no such problem because all types are stored as string and you are able to easily parse and convert them with `int(str)`. The problem is when should I prefer a conversion? There might be some convenience in converting from string to other types: I can use methods of string and bound some checks. But what are the cons?

Comment: You cannot cast a string to an integer. You need to parse the string. Various method to do this - google it

Comment: @EdHeal yes, I understand that. It's not a "cast", but a conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost never. The reason of having types is to specify the intent or the way a method should be used.

If at the end of your call chain you require an int, that should be reflected in your method signatures.

There is also a subtle difference between casting and the int(str). The second one is not a cast but involves some kind of parsing of the string to specify whether the string actually represents a number.

In C++, you'll have to try to parse the string to an int, check if the conversion was successful and continue from there. Why pay for that when you know that you need an int ?

If somehow you are getting strings, you can try and parse them before calling the function. I think it's cleaner this way.

Comment: But, why languages store types as string? As in Java, for instance.

Comment: Languages have variables which store values, the values may have a type defined when you write the program (as in C++) or a type that is defined upon execution (as in Python). The actual mechanism depends on the language, but when you see let's say a value in python, in may be string but upon doing an int(str), the actual value IS an integer.

Comment: Java does not store values as strings (there is int/double/etc) and you specify them when you write your program (although there are various escape hatches you can use). But the main point is not that, the main point is that you have two logical entities ... The value, and it's type. The value may be a integer but the type may be a string, e.g. when you read from a file.